# HYBRIS - Impex cronjob - Log number of lines successfully imported

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

To log successful lines imported, I look at `ImpExImportCronJobModel.valueCount`

When the job is successful it logs a positive number. This is ok.

When the job fails it prints zero in local but in other environments, it logs a negative number.

I am trying to figure out the inconsistency between environments.

Meanwhile, what is expected?

`ImpExImportCronJobModel.valueCount` - can this be negative number? If yes what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The valueCount is set to the number of resolved items from the import.  The fact that is positive does not mean that *all* items have imported.  In reality the resolved count = processed count - dumped count.

I'm not sure how you would get a negative number, as that would imply dumping more lines than were processed ....